# What's the name of Wikipedia's default referencing style?

Tags: citations, wikipedia

What's the name of the Default Referencing Style that Wikipedia Uses? Specifically, I'm looking for the name of the style that is used when you use the referencing styles use by default when you click one of these four options:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean "English Wikipedia"? Or are you really asking of the whole [wikipedia.org](https://www.wikipedia.org) (280 languages)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

As you can see above, references to journal articles from the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nos%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hoover_thermostat) are styled in the following manner:

> Author, First A.; Author, Second B.  (year). "Title goes here". *Journal of failed experiments* **volume** (issue): pages-pages.

This is documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_sources/Example_style#Journal_articles). **It corresponds to the [APA citation style](http://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/apa)**, with additional quotation marks around the paper title (which are not present in the standard APA style). Also, the references are styled as footnotes rather than “(author year)”.

In addition, note that it is not a strict Wikipedia requirement: the [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_sources/Example_style#Journal_articles) I quoted above says:

> There is currently **no consensus on a preferred citation style or system for Wikipedia**. If you cannot decide on which style to use, or if you do not know what information to include, an example partially based on the APA style is given below.

Comment: There's one other difference: APA's version of intext referencing is the parenthesis version, Wikipedia uses footnote referencing.

Comment: The other difference between wiki and APA is that there's also a PubMed Identifier if there is one available. So there are a few differences between APA and the format Wikipedia uses by default

Comment: APA style has a [huge manual](http://www.apastyle.org/) that cover "all" possible cases. Wikipedia is certainly inspired by APA, but it's not the same for all details.